# How to interpret 本质 here?

Tags: meaning

When I look up 本质 I get English meanings like 'essence, nature， innate character', esoteric stuff like that.

学习必须讲究方法，而改进学习方法的**本质目的**，就是要提高学习效率。

I think 本质 here actually means 主要， 最初 and 本质目的 is 'primary aim'.

Could I use 主要 here instead of 本质 and not affect the original meaning?

Comment: I think you are looking for the word "fundamental"

Answer (score 1):

本质 here means *root; ultimate.*

本质目的 = end goal. You can also say 根本目的.

Your sentence sounds fine but isn't the best example to demonstrate usage, because it's kind of obvious. A better example might be:

> 商业活动的本质目的是盈利。The end goal for any commercial activity is making profit.

Comment: Would you accept 本质目的  as 'main aim'?

Comment: @Pedroski 本质 means 'essential/substantial', which is a bit different from 'main'. 'Main aim' is 主要目的.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate it as "essential".

"Essential/本质/根本" is like you peel an onion. "Ultimate/终极" is like you go along the way and reach somewhere eventually. "Primary/主要" is like you have a few rocks and you want the biggest one.

Well the onion example may be inappropriate because there isn't a core and it's always the same when you peel it, but nothing pops into my mind at the moment...

Let's say "essential" is like you peel a chestnut. Hmm this is better.